# How to whitelist Zapier IP addresses in AWS RDS security group

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, zapier, aws-security-group

I've inherited an AWS RDS instance and it's my first run at trying to manage that side of things in the data world, sorry if I'm misunderstanding or overlooking anything!

I'm trying to use Zapier to connect a 3rd party app to our AWS RDS Postgresql database. I've created a new user in postgres and can connect with these credentials from my local machine without issue. However, when I try to connect Zapier to our db with the same credentials, it fails. This is definitely due to the fact that we only allow whitelisted IPs to connect to our db. So, I should be able to whitelist Zapier's IP address(es) and problem solved, yeah?

Unfortunately I'm unable to figure out *which* IPs Zapier needs me to whitelist. [This article](https://zapier.com/apps/postgresql/help) is of no use, because the "We send out database connections from the IP addresses listed here." link is dead. I can find a similar link in the MongoDB connection help page, but it links to, what I think is, [every single AWS IP address](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json).

Surely many before me have been able to set this connection up, so what am I missing? Zapier has been of little assistance to me so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article you link to only the PostreSQL-Link is dead, the other two (MySQL and SQL-Server) work. In both cases the claim, that they're using a static IP to connect to your database ([Source](https://zapier.com/apps/sql-server/help#is-your-database-ip-restricted)):

> This is useful if you use a non-AWS host, for example: Rackspace, HostGator, Linode, DigitalOcean, etc. Zapier connections currently come from static IP addresses. Zapier will make connections to your database from the following IP address:
>
> 54.86.9.50
>
> Important: Don't forget to do both things: open up your firewall and add the IPs to your user GRANT permissions.

The IP **54.86.9.50** is listed in *both* articles so chances are they're using that to create connections to Postgres as well.

I'd try to add `54.86.9.50` to the security group and check if it works.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. My frustration blinded me!